# example template for django rest framework pagination

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use Django REST framework for the first time and looking at the tutorials there is no template examples, What can I use for template? I tried template_name = 'authorListAjax.html' but I get this response https://i.stack.imgur.com/fajhb.jpg

## views.py

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('subject', 'date', 'time_start')  

class AuthorListAll1(ListAPIView):
    template_name = 'authorListAjax.html'
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    paginate_by = 2
    paginate_by_param = 'page_size'
    max_paginate_by = 100
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^ajax/list/$', AuthorListAll1.as_view(), name='ajax_list'),
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery code for Django REST framework pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561821/jquery-code-for-django-rest-framework-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a renderer: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#templatehtmlrenderer

This means adding this line (which tells DRF that the response will be HTML, not JSON):

```
renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
```

Also, you can not set the template name on your view class; the template name belongs to the renderer class. You can either set it directly on the renderer, like this:

```
TemplateHTMLRenderer.template_name = 'authorListAjax.html'
```

or you can overwrite the get method and set it there, like this:

```
return Response({'user': self.object}, template_name='authorListAjax.html')
```

I recommend you the second way, because the first one sets the template name globally, and it might get you in troubles :)