# Jquery code for Django REST framework pagination

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

## I have this json with pagination from Django REST framework but I don't know how to use it.

```
{"count": 18, "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/?page=6&format=json", 
 "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/?page=4&format=json", 
"results": [{"subject": "fd", "date": "2014-06-20", "time_start": "3:36 AM"},
 {"subject": "fdf", "date": "2014-06-14", "time_start": "3:38 AM"}]}
```

## http url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/?page=5&format=json
```

## django urls.py

```
url(r'^ajax/list/$', AuthorListAll1.as_view(), name='ajax_list'),
```

## http url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/
```

I get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/fajhb.jpg

## in django view, is template_name = 'authorListAjax.html' work? why do I get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/fajhb.jpg

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('subject', 'date', 'time_start')  

class AuthorListAll1(ListAPIView):
    template_name = 'authorListAjax.html'
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    paginate_by = 2
    paginate_by_param = 'page_size'
    max_paginate_by = 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define proper renderer classes, you can do it by putting this in your settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}
```

or in your view class, by adding the property:

```
renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer)
```

Comment: I'm getting the template now at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/ but what is the address for that browseable api?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/list/?page=2&format=api This is how to get the api for future reference , Thank You again.